# MQ authentication of client channel fails if certificate replaced with certificate chain

Tags: ssl-certificate, ibm-mq

I have MQ version 6 and the authentication was working with a single personal certificate to validate connection using a client channel. Now the client entity connecting from the other end to the MQ server wants to use a certificate chain with root, intermediate and 2 more levels of certificates. After installing the root and the certificate chain the authentication fails with the below message.

AMQ9637: Channel is lacking a certificate.

Any idea what could have gone wrong? The order of certificates seems to be correct. Thanks in advance for any help or suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

If there had been a problem on the client's end accessing the certificate store, it would have failed and aborted the connection.  The "Channel is lacking a certificate" error suggests that the client participated in the channel negotiation but was unable to find its own certificate when asked.  Some common causes for this include:

- The C client looked for a personal certificate by label and the certificate was loaded into the KDB with a different label.  For example, if my user ID is `t.rob` the C client cert must have a label of `ibmwebspheremqt.rob`.
- The Java/JMS client points the Keystore attribute to the trust store file.  In Java and JMS, the keystore and trust store may be different files or they may be the same file.  Whichever scheme is used, the environment variables that point to the correct files.
- The client was not shut down completely.  After changing a keystore, the old keystore must be flushed from memory.  The queue manager has a `RESET SECURITY TYPE(SSL)` command to do this but a client app does not.  So any app that needs to see the new version of the keystore must be stopped completely, then restarted.  For things like app servers where the app might be shut down separate from the server, the whole server must usually be cycled.

If one of these does not solve the problem, you'll need to update the question with some details such as the type of client, the cert label, the user ID, the platform, etc.